# List uploaded files in django

Tags: python, django

How can I list files after they have been uploaded? I want to display them so they can be viewed and downloaded later.

Here is my code.

models.py

```
class UploadFile(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='files/%Y/%m/%d')
```

forms.py

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.ModelForm): pass

class Meta:
    model = UploadFile
```

views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_file = UploadFile(file = request.FILES['file'])
            new_file.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('main:home'))
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
        data = {'form': form}
        return render_to_response('upload.html', data,
                                  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to get file back from form and save it - just save it using your model. View have to be something like this:

```
    @login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
    def home(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save() # saving model instance
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('main:home'))
        else:
            form = UploadFileForm()

        data = {'form': form}
        return render_to_response('upload.html', data, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and after this you can take all uploaded files from your model:

```
files = [upload_file.file for upload_file in UploadFile.objects.all()]
```

and show them to user

Comment: i did this but it says NameError: name 'UploadFiles' is not defined

Comment: or you miss typed - not 'UploadFiles' - just 'UploadFile', or didn`t import model UploadFile from your models

Comment: ok error went away yeah i didn't import it but im not seeing any file i uploaded do i have to put some in upload.html to able to work

Comment: yes. You need to create view and template, send files from view to template and show them in template.